# How do you install retropie on a raspberry pi 3 using a chromebook?

Tags: retropie

I have received a Raspberry Pi 3 B that worked perfectly and want to use retropie on the Raspberry Pi but I only have access to a samsung chromebook 3. I have formatted the sd card the 32 gb sd card that came with the Raspberry Pi with the files app and followed the instructions listed here (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/chromeos.md) and replaced the raspian file that is instructed with the 2/3 retropie file listed here (https://retropie.org.uk/download/) then I inserted the retropie file into a zip file and then inserted the 32 gb sd card into my Raspberry Pi and inserted the power cord into the Raspberry Pi. When this event occurred the red indicator lights on the sides of the Raspberry Pi turned on but that was the only thing that happened. What do I do?

Comment: Can you write to a SD Card on a chromebook?

Comment: Yes but the chromebook does not recognize the format of the sd.

Comment: What does "does not recognize the format of the sd" mean? What have you tried?

Comment: I can view the contents of the sd card but can not make any changes to it. I have heard from others that if you format the sd using the chromebook files app the raspberry pi won't be able to read off of the sd.

Comment: Do I put retropie into a zip file?

Comment: ok I did it but now the raspberry pi won't even boot the red lights on the side are on but my tv doesn't pick up a signal.

Comment: I used a retropie 2/3 file and put it into a zip file. I go through the steps listed on the page you linked and put it into my raspberry pi. When the pi is turned on the lights on the side turn on but nothing else happens.

Comment: I have edited my post to be in detail.